# Error en certificado de google.com

Tags: google-chrome, navegador-web, certificado-ssl

Quisiera pedir su ayuda con un asunto. Tengo un pc con Windows 10, y de vez en cuando al navegar por internet, y trato de usar google.com, solo para buscar algo, a veces me aparece un error que me indica que el certificado no es válido. A veces esta bien y pasa esto, simplemente es totalmente aleatorio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
También sucede en los demás navegadores como Edge.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisando, al parecer el certificado de google.com se cambia por el de google.com.co, no se porque, pero supongo que por eso no coincide:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y google.com.co funciona pero muy lento, asi como bing.com o yahoo.es. Las imágenes no cargan en la previsualización, y pues otros sitios que usen el recaptcha o alguna api de google.com se bloquean por eso.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También si dejo el computador un rato encendido, después aparece que no tiene conexión a internet:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya he investigado y dice que hay que reiniciar router, borrar datos de navegación, deshabilitar extensiones, etc, pero nada. Si tuvieran alguna sugerencia, o si creen que podría ser un virus, cualquier idea de bienvenida. Gracias

Comment: ¿La fecha y hora de tu computadora es correcta? ¿Tienes algún antivirus instalado? ¿Tienes la última versión de Chrome?

Comment: sip, sip y sip, todo esta bien configurado

Comment: Pues probablemente sea el antivirus. Hay algunos antivirus que filtran los certificados SSL. Intenta desactivando el antivirus a ver si funciona.

Comment: Creo que el problema es que no debería cambiarse los certificados de google.com por el de google.com.co, pero no se por qué pasa eso. :_, alguna idea?